# Using netBeans for PHP development (Apache)

Tags: php, apache, netbeans

I have a project to do in PHP (5) and I want to use netBeans (6.8) as the IDE (Linux). But after a little search I found out that netBeans doesn't have apache2 server.

In that case:

1. Can I use netBeans as my IDE for PHP development? If yes, I would be thankful if you can provide some examples.
2. If not, what are the other alternatives? Please provide some links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working with PHP, Apache, and NetBeans](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-3883/gfxsx?a=view)

Comment: this is a more detailed explanation : http://blogs.sun.com/jonasdias/entry/xampp_with_netbeans

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd really like http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ based on what you're describing you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have Zend Server installed as my Server, but use Netbeans for the majority of my development. the IDE does not necessarily also have to be the server.

You could use Zend Server, or depending on your environment, any other LAMP or WAMP stack. Just point netbeans to your server root.

Comment: Certainly NB can be used like this, and indeed, it's quite nice to have the server be independent of your IDE. You can even use NB to develop and debug on a remote server, if that's the environment. As an aside, note that the latest version of NB is 6.9.x which incorporates quite a few enhancements related to PHP over 6.8.x. My whole team switched to NB when we moved from Windows to Mac development stations, and we're quite happy.